# putting an array into a html table

Tags: php, html, arrays, zend-framework

$result is actually an array which looks like this:

> Array ( [book_title] => Bioethics in the 21st Century [id] => 1424
>   [isbn] => 978-953-307-270-8 [unix_name] =>
>   bioethics-in-the-21st-century [visible_online] => 1 )

This is my view(better said...poor attempt of a view ). I'm trying to get an alignment based on the index of the array. Like so: 
http://pastebin.com/z13PZWe8

```
<table class="datagrid grid_collapsible" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id="webbooks_table">
            <thead>
    <tr class="datagrid_header"
        <td>Book title</td>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>ISBN</td>
        <td>Is it visible online?</td>
    </tr>
        </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($this->basicBwDetails as $result): ?>
        <tr>    
    <td><?=$result;?>  </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </tbody>



</table>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
<table class="datagrid grid_collapsible" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id="webbooks_table">

  <thead>
    <tr class="datagrid_header">
      <td>Book title</td>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>ISBN</td>
      <td>Is it visible online?</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
<?php foreach($this->basicBwDetails as $result): ?>
    <tr>    
      <td><?php echo $result['book_title']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['isbn']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo ($result['visible_online']) ? 'Yes' : 'No'; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

As a side note, `<?=$var;?>` syntax should be avoided since [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) is disabled in many PHP installations, and this was required to use that syntax until PHP 5.4.0

Comment: @DaveRandom - you don't echo on iteration. `<?php $result['book_title']; ?>` won't show anything.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how You got the result form database it will be something like this:

```
<td><?=$result['book_title']?>  </td>
<td><?=$result['id']?>  </td>
<td><?=$result['isbn']?>  </td>
<td><?=$result['visible_online']?>  </td>
```

Or if You're using doctrine:

```
<td><?=$result->book_title?>  </td>
<td><?=$result->id?>  </td>
<td><?=$result->isbn?>  </td>
<td><?=$result->visible_online?>  </td>
```

You should read tutorial, things like that are in it :)
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html

Comment: Please don't get offended your answer was also useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
...
    <tbody>
            <?php foreach($this->basicBwDetails as $result): ?>
            <tr>    
               <?php foreach($result as $cell)?>
                  <td><?=$cell;?>  </td>
               <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </tbody>
...
```

Like this ?